# What does `/*, thisArg*/` mean in the function definition?

Tags: javascript, callback

I am a newbie in JS, and looking at the polyfill definition of the function `map` this question came to my mind: what in the world does the function definition mean? What does the comment `/*, thisArg*/` mean and what does it contain? Is it a sorta variable parameter?

```
/*Array.prototype.map implementation*/
 Array.prototype.map = function (callback/*, thisArg*/) { //what does this mean and why is it set this way?
 var T, A, k;
 if (this == null) {
     throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
 }
 var O = Object(this);
 var len = O.length >>> 0;// QUESTION 1 : What is the need for this line of code?
 if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
     throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
 }
 if (arguments.length > 1) { 
     T = arguments[1];
 }
 //  QUESTION 2 :What is the need for the if condition and why are we assiging T=arguments[1]?
 A = new Array(len);
 k = 0;
 while (k < len) {
     var kValue, mappedValue;
     if (k in O) {
         kValue = O[k];
         mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O); 
         // QUESTION 3: why do we pass T,k and O when all you need is kvalue?
         A[k] = mappedValue;
     }
     k++;
 }
 return A; 
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

/*, thisArg */ is a comment

if (arguments.length > 1) {
T = arguments[1];
}

arguments[1] indicates there's an optional parameter being used the comment gives it a name.